# Deep copy a filtered PySpark dataframe from a Hive query

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting some data from a Hive table and inserting on a dataframe:

```
df = sqlContext.table('mydb.mytable')
```

and I'm filtering a few values that are not useful:

```
df = df[df.myfield != "BADVALUE"]
```

I want to do this on the data frame and not as a `select` query for code design reasons. I noticed that even after I filtered the dataframe, it seems that the query and load operation from Hive is done every single time I operate on the df later:

```
df.groupBy('myfield').mean()
```

This would take a very long time, exactly the same as if I didn't filter the data frame. Is there a way do to a *deep copy* of it to increase performance and reduce the memory footprint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you need to cache your dataframe

```
df.cache()
```

Spark is lazily evaluated. When you perform transformations (such as filter), spark will not actually do anything. Computations won't occur until you do an action (such as show, count, etc). And Spark will not keep any intermediate (final) results. It only keeps the steps needed to create all of the dataframes. To avoid multiple redundant steps (eg reading in the table, filtering out bad values) if you perform multiple actions, you'll need to cache the intermediate dataframe into memory.

Comment: Caching. The code shows that it returns `self`, but it seems that it marks an attribute on the class showing that it was cached.

Comment: Yea it really just updates some meta data of your dataframe without actually caching it. Then, when an action is taken on the dataframe, or on a dataframe that is derived from the cached one, the data will be read in and storeed in memory. 4 & 5 on this site explain it a bit more:. The example is with an RDD, but it's the same with a dataframe. http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/data-exploration-using-spark.html